# Show more than 4 columns in Salesforce Lightning Related Lists

Tags: lightning, related-list

As we have begun adopting Salesforce Lightning for our org, it seems we have run into to issues relating to Related Lists on a custom object record:

1) We cannot show more than 4 columns in a related list view, and
2) Similarly, how are you able to choose which 4 columns are shown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Currently you cannot view more than 4 columns in  lightning related view. There is a idea currently and status shows as **Currently in development**. Hopefully it should be available soon.

**[Idea link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEFbQAM)**

2. You can select which columns you would like to see in related list from page layouts.

**Goto:** Setup->Object Manager-> Select the object-> page layouts -> Edit the page layout you would like to make changes-> scroll down to your related list and click on gear icon (below image)

[image]

Add the columns you would like to see in the selected fields section (below image).
Note that in lightning top4 columns will be displayed in related list.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Take your related lists to the next level. With Enhanced Related Lists, you can show up to 10 columns, resize and sort your columns, perform mass actions, and wrap text.

**Where**: This change applies to Lightning Experience in Essential, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.

**How**: From the related lists component in the Lightning App Builder, select Enhanced List from the Related List Type dropdown (1). You can customize how many records to display at once, and choose whether to show the list view action bar.

Choosing Enhanced List affects all related lists in the component (2). To customize which columns appear in a particular related list, edit the related list in the page layout editor and add more fields.

[image: More than four fields in related list]

Read more here:- [More than four fields in related list](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/03/26/more-than-four-fields-in-related-list-in-lightning-experience/)

Comment: Note though that this only applies to related lists that are wide. In Lightning, it is also possible to use narrow related lists and then this not apply, even though Salesforce lets you choose Enhanced List and the number of displayed records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sortable Data Grid/Enhanced Lightning Grid for this! You can pretty customize every little detail including the number of columns. Takes more effort than the out of the box related list but it's all point and click.

More here - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EVK8iUAH

Answer (score -1):

In Lightning, go to Setup then Object Manager and  find the object on which the related list based. Drill down on the object name and select Search Layouts and then Search Results, click dropdown and select Edit. Add the columns you want (move from Available to the Selected fields), arrange their sequence and Save.  This should affect the display of the fields/columns in the object tab and any related lists based on the object.